# create a python dictionary based on another dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have the the following dict that contains the following data:

```
response = {"status":"ERROR","email":"EMAIL_INVALID","name":"NAME_INVALID"}
```

I am trying to create a new dict based on 'response' that is suposed to look like the following:

```
{'api_error': {'list': [{'converted_value': 'No special characters allowed.',
                         'field': 'name',
                         'value': 'NAME_INVALID'},
                        {'converted_value': 'invalid email',
                         'field': 'email',
                         'value': 'EMAIL_INVALID'}],
               'status': 'ERROR'},
 'email': 'EMAIL_INVALID',
 'email_label': 'invalid email',
 'name': 'NAME_INVALID',
 'name_label': 'No special characters allowed.',
 'status': 'ERROR'}
```

So far I have been able to do the following:

```
ret = {}
for k in response:
        if k != 'status':
                ret[k+"_label"] = convert(response[k])
                ret[k] = response[k]
        else:
            ret[k] = convert(response[k])
```

where 'convert' function translates each value of response. for example NAME_INVALID is converted to  'No special characters allowed.' and so on. Here is the output of what above code is doing:

```
{"status":"ERROR","name_label":"No special characters allowed.",
"email_label":"invalid email","name":"NAME_INVALID","email":"EMAIL_INVALID"}
```

I am getting problem creating the rest of the dictionary. The one whose key is 'api_error'. What will be the most efficient way of doing that?

Comment: Where is the `name_label` value introduced? I don't see it in the original response or your code sample.

Comment: Its coming from a function called convert that convert the value to the appropriate language in use. For example for NAME_INVALID, it returns 'No special characters allowed.'

Comment: You may want to post that function also for a more complete answer.

Comment: It looks like you are duplicating the same information in more than one place in your data structure. That is probably a bad design. It makes modification of the data error-prone -- you have to remember to change it in multiple places. Are you sure you want this data structure?

Comment: Well, thats true @unutbu and I am aware of that. But for now, I need it to be like that. I am rewriting some api in python and for now I need to have the same response as its with the old one. In future I will change the response and make it more efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pprint

response = {"status": "ERROR", "email": "EMAIL_INVALID", "name":
            "NAME_INVALID"}


def convert(label):
    return {'NAME_INVALID': 'No special characters allowed',
            'EMAIL_INVALID': 'invalid email',
            'ERROR': 'ERROR'}[label]

ret = {}
for k in response:
    if k != 'status':
        ret[k + "_label"] = convert(response[k])
        ret[k] = response[k]
        info = {'converted_value': ret[k + "_label"],
                'field': k,
                'value': response[k]}
        (ret.setdefault('api_error', {})
            .setdefault('list', [])
            .append(info))
    else:
        ret[k] = convert(response[k])
        ret.setdefault('api_error', {})['status'] = ret[k]
pprint.pprint(ret)
```

yields

```
{'api_error': {'list': [{'converted_value': 'invalid email',
                         'field': 'email',
                         'value': 'EMAIL_INVALID'},
                        {'converted_value': 'No special characters allowed',
                         'field': 'name',
                         'value': 'NAME_INVALID'}],
               'status': 'ERROR'},
 'email': 'EMAIL_INVALID',
 'email_label': 'invalid email',
 'name': 'NAME_INVALID',
 'name_label': 'No special characters allowed',
 'status': 'ERROR'}
```

Answer (score 0):

make one more function that will be like

```
def make2nddict(response):
for k in response:
    if k != 'status':
        d = {}
        d['converted_value'] = convert(k)
        d['field'] = k
        d['value'] = response[k]
        arr.append(d)
    else:
        final[k] = response[k]
final['list'] = arr

arr= []
final = {}

def convert(error):
    if error == 'NAME_INVALID':
        return 'No special characters allowed'
    elif error == 'EMAIL_INVALID':
        return 'EMAIL_INVALID'
    else:
        return error

ret = {}
for k in response:
    if k != 'status':
            ret[k+"_label"] = convert(response[k])
            ret[k] = response[k]
    else:
        ret[k] = convert(response[k])
```

put output of noth the function in your api_error dictionary
good luck

Answer (score 0):

Here the full code: ---

```
>>>response = {"status":"ERROR","email":"EMAIL_INVALID","name":"NAME_INVALID"}
>>>def convert(parameter):
       if parameter == "NAME_INVALID":
           return "No special characters allowed."
       if parameter =="EMAIL_INVALID":
           return "invalid email"

>>>def newdic(response):
       ret={}
       response_keys = response.keys()
       response_keys.remove("status")
       if response['status']=="ERROR":
            ret = response
            ret['api_error'] ={'list':[],'status':"ERROR"}
            for key in response_keys:
                 ret[key+"_label"] = convert(response[key])
                 dic={}
                 dic['converted_value'] = convert(response[key])
                 dic['field'] = key
                 dic['value'] = response[key]
                 ret['api_error']['list'].append(dic)

       return ret
```

Here is the answer:--

```
>>>newdic(response)

{'status': 'ERROR',
 'email_label': 'invalid email',
 'name': 'NAME_INVALID',
 'name_label': 'No special characters allowed.', 
 'api_error': {
 'email': 'EMAIL_INVALID',
 'list': [{'field': 'email', 'value': 'EMAIL_INVALID',
             'converted_value': 'invalid email'},
             {'field': 'name', 'value': 'NAME_INVALID',
             'converted_value': 'No special characters allowed.'}
            ],
 'status': 'ERROR'}
}
```